# Uncaught TypeError: wmsLayers.getSource is not a function

Tags: openlayers, wms, popup, getfeatureinfo, web-gis

[image]

wms appears but when clicked an error appears like this and the popup does not appear

I want to use WMS GetFeatureInfo (Tile Layer) whose info is taken from WMS Geoserver to display popup information

```
import { Map, View } from "ol";
import TileLayer from "ol/layer/Tile";
import OSM from "ol/source/OSM";
import { fromLonLat } from "ol/proj";
import Overlay from "ol/Overlay";
import TileWMS from 'ol/source/TileWMS';
import scorKabBgr from "./layer/kabBogorScoring";
import scorKotBgr from "./layer/kotBogorScoring";
import admKabBgr from "./layer/admKabBgr";
import admKotBgr from "./layer/admKotBogor";
import poiDamkar from "./layer/poiDamkar";
import sungaiKabupaten from "./layer/sungaiKabupaten";
import sungaiKota from "./layer/sungaiKota";
import $ from "jquery";

const container = document.getElementById("popup-2");
const conten = document.getElementById("popup-content");
const closer = document.getElementById("popup-closer");

export const overlay = new Overlay({
    element: container,
    autoPan: {
        animation: {
            duration: 250,
        },
    },
});



const wmsLayers = [
    { layer: poiDamkar, checkboxId: "customPoiDamkar" },
    { layer: scorKabBgr, checkboxId: "customCheckBoxScoreKabBgr" },
    { layer: scorKotBgr, checkboxId: "customCheckBoxScoreKotBgr" },
    { layer: admKabBgr, checkboxId: "customCheckBoxAdmKabBgr" },
    { layer: admKotBgr, checkboxId: "customCheckBoxAdmKotBgr" },
    { layer: sungaiKabupaten, checkboxId: "customCheckBoxsungaiKabupaten" },
    { layer: sungaiKota, checkboxId: "customCheckBoxsungaiKota" },
    // Tambahkan informasi untuk lapisan WMS lainnya di sini
];

// Fungsi untuk menambah atau menghapus lapisan WMS dari peta
function toggleWMSLayer(layer, checked) {
    if (checked) {
        map.addLayer(layer);
    } else {
        map.removeLayer(layer);
    }
}

wmsLayers.forEach(({ layer, checkboxId }) => {
    const checkbox = document.getElementById(checkboxId);
    checkbox.addEventListener("change", function () {
        toggleWMSLayer(layer, this.checked);
    });
});

const osmLayer = new TileLayer({
    source: new OSM(),
});

const view = new View({
    center: fromLonLat([106.71667, -6.58333]),
    zoom: 10.5,
});
const map = new Map({
    overlays: [overlay],
    target: "map",
    layers: [osmLayer],
    view: view,
    // view: new View({
    //     center: fromLonLat([106.71667, -6.58333]),
    //     zoom: 10.5,
    // }),
});

map.on('singleclick', function (evt) {
    document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = '';
    const viewResolution = /** @type {number} */ (view.getResolution());
    const url = wmsLayers.getSource().getFeatureInfoUrl(
        evt.coordinate,
        viewResolution,
        // 'EPSG:4326',
        'EPSG:3857',
        { 'INFO_FORMAT': 'text/html' },
    );
    if (url) {
        fetch(url)
            .then((response) => response.text())
            .then((html) => {
                document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = html;
            });
    }
});

map.on('pointermove', function (evt) {
    if (evt.dragging) {
        return;
    }
    const data = osmLayer.getData(evt.pixel);
    const hit = data && data[3] > 0; // transparent pixels have zero for data[3]
    map.getTargetElement().style.cursor = hit ? 'pointer' : '';
});

export default map;
```

Answer (score 1):

`wmsLayers` is defined in your code as:

```
const wmsLayers = [
    {...},
    {...},
    {...},
]
```

It is an array (of dictionaries) and it does not have any functions.  Therefore the code `const url = wmsLayers.getSource().getFeatureInfoUrl(...` makes no sense.  there is no `getSource()` function on `wmsLayers`.

In fact, even the elements within the `wmsLayers` list are not layers themselves.

It's difficult to be certain (due to the `import` statements hiding the actual code), but it appears as though the `layer` property of each dictionary item in your `wmsLayers` list is probably a layer.  If this is the case, then you could use the following to access that layer and its source:

```
wmsLayers[i].getSource().getFeatureInfoUrl(...
```

... where `i` is the index of the layer item in the `wmsLayers` array.

But I think you'd be better of simply getting the layer information from the `map` object at that point.  Something like:

```
map.getAllLayers().forEach((layer) => {
    const url = this.getSource().getFeatureInfoUrl(...
});
```

Of course, you may also want to avoid running that for the OSM layer, which would require a little extra code.